# How to binding the selected value into the picker and save this edit page?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

I have this Edit page where it has an Id passed from the Detail page. Then called web api service to get Categories as well as the Activity. This code below was adapted from the Add page btw.

It has 2 issues:

1. Managed to get the picker list BUT then not sure how to binding this from selected Activity.
2. How to save this as the binding name is different in XAML ie. Activity.Name VS Name etc etc. What did I do wrong?

How to solve these?

**Code below:**

**ActivityEditPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Entry Placeholder="Name" Text="{Binding Activity.Name}"></Entry>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Activity.CategoryId}">
        </Picker>
        <Entry Placeholder="No of minutes" Text="{Binding Activity.NoOfMinutes}"></Entry>
        <Editor Placeholder="Description" Text="{Binding Activity.Description}"></Editor>
        <Button Text="Save" BackgroundColor="#340E22" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" HeightRequest="40" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace AthlosifyMobileApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ActivityEditPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ActivityEditPage(int id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ActivityEditViewModel(Navigation, id);
        }

    }
}
```

**ActivityEditViewModel.cs:**

```
using AthlosifyMobileApp.Helpers;
using AthlosifyMobileApp.Models;
using AthlosifyMobileApp.Services;
using AthlosifyMobileApp.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AthlosifyMobileApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivityEditViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly ApiService apiService = new ApiService();

        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private string _description;
        private int _noOfMinutes;
        private int _categoryId;
        private string _categoryName;
        private Command _saveCommand;
        private List<Category> _categories;
        private Category _selectedCategory;
        private Activity _activity;

        public ActivityEditViewModel(INavigation navigation, int Id)
        {
            this.Navigation = navigation;
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await GetCategories();
                Activity = await GetActivity(Id);
            });
        }

        public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

        public Activity Activity
        {
            get { return _activity;  }
            set
            {
                _activity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                _description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int  NoOfMinutes
        {
            get { return _noOfMinutes; }
            set
            {
                _noOfMinutes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int CategoryId
        {
            get { return _categoryId; }
            set
            {
                _categoryId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string CategoryName
        {
            get { return _categoryName; }
            set
            {
                _categoryName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public List<Category> Categories
        {
            get { return _categories; }
            set
            {
                _categories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Categories");
            }
        }

        public Category SelectedCategory
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedCategory;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Command SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new Command(ExecuteSaveCommand, CanSave));
            }
        }


        async void ExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            var newItem = new Activity
            {
                Id = Id,
                OwnerId = Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_UserId, ""),
                Name = Name,
                CategoryId = SelectedCategory.Id,
                CategoryName = SelectedCategory.Name,
                Description = Description,
                NoOfMinutes = NoOfMinutes
            };

            var response = await apiService.UpdateActivity(Id, newItem);
            if (!response)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Something wrong", "Alright");
            }
            else
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityListPage());
            }
        }

        bool CanSave()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
        }

        public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategories()
        {
            CategoryResult categoryResult = await apiService.GetCategories();
            return Categories = categoryResult.Results;
        }

        public async Task<Activity> GetActivity(int id)
        {
            Activity activity = await apiService.GetActivity(id);
            return activity;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

**Category.cs**

```
    public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Activity.cs:**

```
 public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NoOfMinutes { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"`

Comment: @Jason in my web api called for Activity ... i'm flatting up the JSON objects (DTO approach) so no category object in such ... only CategoryID and CategoryName along with other activities properties

Comment: your Picker is bound to a List<Category>, so you must have Category objects

Comment: @jason I've updated the code by adding the 2 models (Category and Activity). As you can see in the Activity model, I've flatten up the Category.

Comment: BTW ... my picker list is working OK. I can see the list of Categories BUT the problem how do I preselected this from Activity.CategoryId ? For instance if the particular Activity (Id =  5) and has a Category assigned (Category ID = 2)

Comment: just initialize SelectedCategory in your VM: `SelectedCategory = Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == selected_category_id)`

Comment: The world is in good hands when Jason is back

Comment: Managed to fix the first part which populating the picker from the Activity. Next question how to save this edit as the value from the XAML is binding specifically using Activity.Name, Activity.NoOfMinutes, etc etc ?!?!

Comment: Since the `ActivityEditViewModel` has implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so the value is updated synchronously, and you can get the value directly and save it.